# Boolean and sharedpreference

Tags: android, eclipse, boolean

Hey i am trying to make my own app, i have already searched the web for info and i didn't understand the solutions other people found helpfull. but i have a little problem. I want the app to save the boolean value stopValue, when i close the app, but when i try this, it doesn't save the value when i close the app, instead it set the value to true.

How do i fix this?

Thanks for your help.

```
public class Main extends Activity{

Button bStart, bStop;
TextView tvDate, tvKm;
Spinner spinner1;
boolean stopValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    tvKm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvKm);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    boolean stopValue = false;
    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("stopValue", 1);
    stopValue = sp.getBoolean("stop", false);

    stopValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stop", stopValue);

    if(stopValue){
        bStart.setText("Start");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent start = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.START");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        });
    }
    if(stopValue == false){
        bStart.setText("Stop");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent stop = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.STOP");
                startActivity(stop);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("stopValue", 1);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean("stop", true);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call super.onPause after the commit like this:-

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("stopValue", 1);
     Editor edit = sp.edit();
     edit.putBoolean("stop", stopValue);
     edit.commit();
     super.onPause();


}
```

Comment: It works.. Thanks.. Is that because the pause method is called before it saves the value?

Comment: Yes, the framework pauses the activity when you call super.onPause()

Answer (score 1):

You are putting true in when trying to save and not the variable.

Comment: I tried to edit that now, and when i load the app it keeps load it to false.. i have tried to change the load preference also to a variable, but that doesn't help.